# Index Management

Tags: mysql, index-tuning

I have two tables in MySQL 8, table A with primary key and table B with a foreign key of the same type on column 1. table B has an index on column 1. If I want to change the index on table/column B1, is it safe to create a new index on the column `(B1)`, then delete the old index?

By "change index" I want to say, add another column and sort order to the index. Like:

```
create index b1_b2_IDX on b (b1 DESC, b2 ASC) ;
```

Comment: What do you mean with "change the index"?

Comment: What do you mean by "safe"? If you're asking if any data from the table can get lost when deleting an index: No (unless there is an unlikely bug in the DBMS of course).

Comment: By "change index" I want to say, add another column and sort order to the index. like `create index b1_b2_IDX on b (1 DESC, 2 ASC) .

Comment: By "safe" I want to know if I'll mess up the relationship with the primary/foreign key constraint by swapping indexes on column B1

Comment: Can you post the code (`CREATE TABLE` statements and how you want to change the index)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you can do this in 2 statements. The first adding the new index and the second dropping the old one. If you tried the reverse order, MySQL will complain because the `FOREIGN KEY` constraint requires an index.

Or - even better - with a single statement, that drops the existing index and adds the new one:

```
alter table b
  drop index b1_idx,
  add index b1_b2_idx 
    (b1 desc, b2 asc) ;
```

Test at **[sqlfiddle.com](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/83336d/1)**.

Comment: Cool. So to confirm, by changing the index like this, it will not have an effect on the foreign key?

Comment: No, the FK will have no problem. The new index will be used from the change and after, for enforcing the FK.